# Comments with subcomments

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display comments and sub comments using one query, the sub comments are only nested once so i you cannot have sub comments of sub-comment. Below is the code i have but it only gives me one of the sub comments when there is more than one. I'm only using * for the purpose of this question.

```
SELECT c.*, sc.* 
FROM
comments c 
LEFT JOIN
sub_comments sc 
ON c.coment_id = sc.snippet_id 
WHERE
c.post_id = '" . $cat_id_var . "' 
GROUP BY
c.comment_id
```

I know there has to be a simple answer but can't figure it out. I thought after that all comments and sub comments should be in the same table also?

Comment: I would change your table structure so comments and sub-comments are in one table. See here for my example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406744/php-mysql-comment-reply-table-structure/10406772#10406772

Comment: So if i put them in the same table and the sub comments will have a parent id relating to the comment in which it belongs, how do i order them so sub comments come right after the comments in which it belongs?

Comment: If you click that link in the comment above, I've included some sample code which recursively runs through all comments and puts the sub comments immediately following its parent comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Set Sail Media, you should definitely think about changing your DB structure. But in your example reason of "only one of the sub comments" is in `GROUP BY` parameter. Just remove it and you'll get all of the sub-comments at once.

Comment: thanks. I did try that but then i get the comment then the sub-comment1, then the same comment and sub-comment2

Comment: @johnwilliams Right. That's the only way to get all the sub-comments having such DB structure. Now you should just "group" and output those comments and sub-comments using your native language (PHP?) features, not with MySQL.